# Problemas al graficar centroides con función scatter

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Me encuentro realizando un trabajo de clusterización con KMeans. Pandas, numpy, matplotlib son las demás herramientas que invoco en el código.
A título informativo, les paso las líneas con las cuales creo un array que contiene 3 variables para que el algoritmo realice la respectiva clasificación:

```
datos=pd.read_csv("base2.csv",";")
df=pd.DataFrame(datos)
x=df['prest']
y=df['depos']
z=df['irreg']
X=np.array(list(zip(x,y,z))).reshape(len(x),3)
```

Después de esto realizo la curva el codo, fit, predict... y todo sale bien.

Con el código que ven a continuación realizo la gráfica mostrando los agrupamientos:

```
for i in range(len(X)):
    print("coordenada: ",X[i]," etiqueta: ",labels[i])
    plt.plot(X[i][0],X[i][1],colors[labels[i]],markersize=10)
```

Y queda bárbaro:
  [image]

Ahora bien ¿Cuál es el problema? Estoy usando scatter para tratar de colocar los centroides en esa gráfica... pero no puedo. Fallo en todos los tiros. Estuve leyendo que scatter solo acepta dos variables de entrada y, en mi caso, tengo 3, que seguramente se ampliarán a 7.

```
plt.scatter(centroids[:,0],centroids[:,1],marker="x",s=150,linewidths=5,zorder=10)
```

¿Serían tan amables de indicarme cómo puedo incorporar en esa gráfica todos los centroides? Si tengo dos... aparecen bien, pero scatter no me permite más que esa cantidad.

Comment: Hola, podrías agregar una parte de los datos para hacer poder reproducir tu problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias, Gustavo.
el set de datos es el siguiente:
prest depos irreg
14909039 865880 19432
10416111 7534483 43709
4242448 7125502 16853
3859572 3124409 37520
3382739 2931618 240510
3285623 4638218 51834
2995641 6628308 445593
2989940 3763023 45438
2958952 2517817 8833
2801325 1250729 416969
2736308 873192 1025
2605754 1993841 101418
2599020 5624465 59450
2499260 2507475 32377
2485576 1864770 207181
2382163 16093028 94325
2317782 3444722 52664
2199968 2218860 4002
2177060 571917 496953
2085225 2931705 16603

Comment: es un dataset de 3 columna, que luego cargo en el np.array, pero tengo problemas con esto:

plt.scatter(centroids[:,0],centroids[:,1],marker="x",s=150,linewidths=5,zorder=10)

no encuentro la forma de colocar los centroides en la gráfica.

Comment: esto está mejor así:
"prest";"depos";"irreg"
14909039;865880;19432
10416111;7534483;43709
4242448;7125502;16853
3859572;3124409;37520
3382739;2931618;240510
3285623;4638218;51834
2995641;6628308;445593
2989940;3763023;45438
2958952;2517817;8833
2801325;1250729;416969
2736308;873192;1025
2605754;1993841;101418
2599020;5624465;59450
2499260;2507475;32377
2485576;1864770;207181
2382163;16093028;94325
2317782;3444722;52664
2199968;2218860;4002
2177060;571917;496953
2085225;2931705;16603
2084646;9620839;10581
2052351;3008589;9241
2051150;3953970;28666
1968113;4131267;401901

Comment: puedes añadir esa información a la pregunta, en vez de crear un comentario. Respecto a tu problema, ¿qué es lo que sucede exactamente cuando ejecutas la funcion `scatter`?  Lanza algún error, dibuja lo que no es? no dibuja nada? Porque cuando la uso tal como la escribiste, **sí** dibuja los centroides (https://imgur.com/a/nVGpStw)

Comment: me quiero matar, gustavo. hace días que vengo corriendo el algoritmo y siempre me sale algún problema... lo ejecuto ahora y no me arroja ningún error.
Previamente no se dibujaban los centroides, para nada, como en la imagen que puse en el comentario principal: se ven los agrupamientos, pero no los centroides.
Espero que no se "rompa" esto y siga funcionando, xq no entiendo qué pasó.
Agradezco mucho tu ayuda, sos muy amable.

Comment: Hay una versión 3D de scatter: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/mplot3d/scatter3d.html